# MQ distribution list in C#

Tags: ibm-mq

Can we access Websphere MQ distribution list in c# ? .Net manual "csqzav07" does not provide any information on this. If any one has tried it already or can share any info on this, that would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks Shashi! I have submitted the RFE.  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=viewRfe&CR_ID=29526

Comment: Shashi, you should move that to an answer so it can be voted and accepted.

Comment: Moved my comments as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current MQ .NET API does not support distribution list. If you like you may submit a RFE to IBM at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=submitRfe